# SEO for multiple product pages

Tags: multiple-domains

I have a domain with 16products and URL structure for that pages are like

www.domain.com/product1
www.domain.com/product2
www.domain.com/product3........................

Now my question how to promote my sites using link building because if i do daily 40 submissions for each product(suppose i do for 3 products) then total submissions for the day will be 120.

I think this may become over promotion because indirectly we are promoting home page only.

Do you think this will penalize my site or shall i continue doing.

One more question is which format is better for domain i.e.,

www.domain.com/product1 (or) www.product1.com

Please let me know....

Thanking U in Advance......................

Answer (score 1):

Deep linking is ok, google actually like deep linked sites, but first make sure your homepage is strongly linked.

Answer (score 0):

To address your second question, all else being equal, `www.product1.com` would probably rank better than `www.domain.com/product1`.

The operative phrase here is "all else being equal", which of course is seldom the case.